# How do I get content of an inner JSON value in python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, database

How do I get content of an inner JSON value?
For example, I want to get the value of Value2 (2) -

```
{
  "JsonString": {
    "InnerJsonString": [
      {
        "Value1": "1",
        "Value2": "2",
        "Value3": "3",
        "Value4": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If `data` is your dictionary: `data["JsonString"]["InnerJsonString"][0]["Value2"]`

Comment: Is this JSON? Or is this a `dict`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json    
with open("data.json", 'r') as jsonRaw:
    data = json.loads(jsonRaw.read())
    print(data["JsonString"]["InnerJsonString"][0]["Value2"]) # prints 2
```